# Could you share some insights on processing a list when using multiprocessing? (A scenario is given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

**Scenario**

I have a long `list` in which each element is a `string`, and now I want to do the same operation for every element by using some functions. Considering the `list`'s length, I want to use `multiprocessing` to create some `Process` to process this `list`. Each `Process` processes only a portion of the elements of the list. To save time in this way.

**In the code below:**

1. I create a `multiprocessing.Manager` to make my `ls` can be shared between the 2 child processes.
2. Then I create a `multiprocessing.Pool`, hoping for two processes to be created. One `Process` do `func()` on `ls[0:100000]`, and another do `func()` on `ls[100000:200000]`.
3. Every result of `my_operation()` on `ls[index]` is written in-place.

**Example code (using *2* processes):**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

# len(ls) = 200000
ls = ['a', 'b', ...]  

# Each element of the scopes below is the scope to be processed by the process. 
# (I want to use 2 processes in this example)
scopes = [ (0, 100000), (100000, 200000) ]  

m = Manager()
ls = m.list(ls)  # create a shared list for child processes


def func(range_start, range_end):
    for index in range(range_start, range_end):
        ls[index] = my_operation(ls[index])

def my_operation(str):
    return str

with Pool(2) as pool:
    pool.starmap_async(func, scopes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Questions**

1. Is it a good idea to read and write on the same list when using `multiprocessing` to deal with different scopes of this list?
2. How to improve my code? (change `Manager` to something else? lesser shared state and how to achieve that? ...)

Thank you!

Comment: Looking through the implementation of `multiprocessing.Manager` we can see that the implementation uses a named pipe on Windows and a Unix domain socket on Unix like operating systems. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L151 Of course these are private methods that can change at any time. Those techniques for IPC are reasonably efficient, and have a big advantage over shared memory segments in terms of simplicity and ease of use for dynamically sized data. However, if you are looking for speed, you should allocate an Array of shared memory.